# How to create and connect to a TTY in a docker container from outside the container?

Tags: javascript, docker, terminal, tty

I want the input/output (tty) of a binary debugged in GDB (running in Docker) as a NodeJS stream.

GDB can seperate its output and the binary's output by using the `tty <tty>` command. I want to interact with this TTY, but it is in a Docker container. Is there anyway to expose the TTY?

So far, I've tried `chvt` while exec'ing from the container (through Dockerode) and reading the output stream, but it doesn't work.

Running GDB in container with `gdb -i=mi --tty=<some tty>`

I want to attach using e.g. exec:

`let exec:Exec = await container.exec({
        AttachStdin: true,
        AttachStdout: true,
        AttachStderr: true,
        Cmd: ['chvt', '69'],
        Tty: true
    });
    let execProc = await exec.start({Tty: true});
    let sock = execProc.output.connection;
    sock.pipe(<somewhere>); //tty of binary running in GDB can be interacted via pipe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let containerExecStream = async (container: Container,cmd: string[]) => {
    let exec = await container.exec({
        AttachStdin: true,
        AttachStdout: true,
        AttachStderr: true,
        Tty: true,
        Cmd:['bash', '-c', 'socat pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/gdbout,waitslave -']});
    let out = await exec.start({Tty: true});
    return <Socket>out.output.connection;
}
```